# Is Cherokee, Mono, and Linux truly a viable alternative to Windows and IIS for production ASP.NET web sites?

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

I have played with Apache and Mono and .NET on Linux in the past, but I have yet to deploy any significant production sites to that stack.  I recently found Cherokee and an article about enabling [FastCGI Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Cherokee) support and wondered if anyone had any good or bad war stories about delivering ASP.NET on a Linux stack.

Comment: I ended up going to the [SuseGallery][1] and did a quick search for Mono and found [JEOS Mono ASP.net][2] which was already setup for what I wanted. I have just started using for some ASP.net migration trials on Windows with VirtualBox. I just needed to start Apache and set up port forwarding. [1]: susegallery.com [2]: susegallery.com/a/0uPadf/jeos-mono-aspnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a 100% FOSS user myself, I would like to say yes:

But it works fine until you realize that a library is half implemented and it is new and cool and would be really useful (LINQ to SQL as an example)

Comment: I will take that as a YMMV, test before you pay for hosting somewhere. :)  About what I thought, just hoped for some first hand war stories.  I guess I will just have to write them myself.